# Is there a hitching post in Blackwater?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I have been donuts around Blackwater looking for a hitching post to tie my new found horse to replace my ole' jalopy, is there a hitching post in the city to be found or do I have to ride elsewhere to swap out?

Answer (score 2):

according to [this](http://au.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/reddeadredemption/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-54990773&pid=957922) there is one near the government building to the left of the courtyard.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a number to be found around the outskirts of Blackwater at the houses and very few (if any) in the centre of town or by the water.

Answer (score -1):

There is one on the outskirts of town, to the left of the doctor building on the other side of the street.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is one in front of the train station.